# My mate-weather applet does not work

Tags: weather, panel-applets

My [mate-weather applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJsQD.png) has not worked for a long time. I use Ubuntu Mate 18.04 and I am located in Lima - Peru. Only for the city of Lima it does not work, but the other cities do. That could be happening?

Comment: I can't get weather for this geographical location on 16.04 LTS too, so this is aviationweather server (or selected meteorological station) issue. You can try to select some near city (as Pisco) instead. Check map here - https://aviationweather.gov/metar .